# Get CKEditor contents without updating the textarea

Tags: ckeditor

Fairly new to CKEditor here. I'm aware that you need to call the `updateElement()` method for CKEditor to send the current editor content to the related textarea element. From there, you can call the `getData()` function to get the content. (Although I don't understand why there are two steps to get the editor content, instead of one.)

However, I want to get the current content *directly* from the editor, *without* changing the related textarea content. Is there a CKEditor method to achieve that, or is it a case of using jQuery to find the editor content?

Answer (score 1):

[The `getData` method](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData) will return the raw HTML from the editor.

Comment: `getData()` seems to return the contents of the related <textarea> element, not the editor itself. I want to get the content direct from the editor.

Comment: @ingredient_15939: No, `getData()` returns the content of the editor. I've tried on v3.6 and v4.0, and calling `getData()` returns the content of the editor; the value of the `<textarea>` remains blank.

Comment: Richard Deeming is right. I am 100% sure about that.

Comment: That's how I expected it to behave, but doesn't in my case. I'll do some testing. Here, getData() always returns the value before any editing was done. I guess there must be a reason. Thanks for the help.